# Xamarin Essentials not getting location when app is in the background

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an app that has the location service running in the background (the code I've used is based off this https://github.com/jfversluis/XFBackgroundLocationSample/tree/main).

When the app is in the foreground, the location service runs fine and I can get the current location and do with it as I need to. However, when the app is in the background, the code to grab the location still runs, but the returned using either `Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(geolocation)` or `Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync()` both return `null`.

Should both of these calls (from Xam.Essentials) be returning null when the app is in the background or is there a way to ensure that the location is actually obtained?

I'm not sure about the `BootBroadcastReceiver` in the example code - my class receiver is in `<mypackagge>.Services.BootBroadcastReceiver` while the example is in `<example>.BootBroadcastReceiver` - it's been a long time since I've used a `BroadcastReceiver`, so I may have that wrong.

Comment: First, you can check if the `ACCESS_BACKGROUD_LOCATION` permission have been added. Then, please be aware that you might need to adjust battery saver settings on some devices manually to allow the application to keep working in the background.

Comment: That permission has been set. I'll check the battery saver, but I have a feeling that has already been set for working in the background

Comment: You should check for 'ACCESS_BACKGROUD_LOCATION' permission, you should get location on foreground service, you may need to set up wake lock.